# What is the meaning of (half a notion for something)?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

What is the meaning of (**half a notion for ..**) in this context?

What is left is attachment to yourself: a recognition of worth and
the wish that it be preserved. Thus, **half a notion for**
approaching middle age. Can you separate attachment
from concern, grieving your own mortality in advance,
giving up the need to persist forever, while saving the
desire for a better life?

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Please say where you found this sentence and provide a link if available. Also, you will find this [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) helpful.

Comment: Let's say you'd want a full approach to moving into middle age, not part of an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "half a notion for approaching middle age" here means "a vague idea on how to approach middle age" or "some sense of what to do when experiencing middle age".